# simplifying a Big-O expression

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

say I had the expression:

```
O(10n) * O(4n^2)
```

I want to simplify it. If we have multiplication between the terms, are we able to drop the lower-growing one?

for example:

```
O(10n * 4n^2)
= O(n^2)
```

or would it be

```
= O(n * n^2)
```

I am expecting it to be `O(n * n^2)` but I am not sure.

Comment: No [tag:java] here.

Comment: Remove all the constant factors. So, *O(10N)* = *O(N)*, by definition. Similarly *O(4N^2)* = *O(N^2)*, by definition. So you already have *O(N)*O(N^2)*, which by inspection = *O(N^3)*.

Comment: Maybe it would help you to think of concrete functions that belong to those classes (e.g. the function f(n) = n in O(10n)) and try multiplying them, then see whether you can classify the result.

Comment: This is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: @Ry- I've been staring at your comment on and off for an hour and I can't make head or tail of it. In any case the algebraic reduction I gave is a lot simpler than any experimental approach.

Comment: @RaymondChen [tag:big-o] notation and complexity theory of algorithms is a branch of computer science. It has no real use in mathematics proper.

Comment: @user207421, Wikipedia on [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) starts with *"Big O notation is a mathematical notation..."*. In the *Usage* section, it says *"Big O notation has two main areas of application: (1) In mathematics... (2) In computer science"*. Similarly the Wikipedia article on [Computational complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) starts with *"In theoretical computer science and mathematics..."*.

Comment: @user207421: You were the one that also couldn’t make head or tail of a multiple-choice question with *two* blanks earlier, yeah? I’ll wait and see what the OP makes of it.

Comment: @user207421 Regardless of whether it is a mathematics question, it is certainly not a computer programming question. There is no computer program.

Comment: *Of course* it's a mathematical notation, *much used in computer science,* like a lot of other mathematical notations, and not much elsewhere. *Ergo,* Raymond and Tim, it is computer scientists who should answer. You could make a case for moving it to the computer-science site, but not to the mathematics site. And, *according to Wikipedia* (which I have edited quite a lot myself), Wikipedia is not a reliable resource, and [not so great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Why_Wikipedia_is_not_so_great).

Comment: It is a question you'll find in  programming interviews and/or while studying computer science.  Perhaps this would be better received here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand out what you have and start with the polynomials before you apply big O, which is going to pull out the highest order polynomial as the bounding function:

```
let's imagine that g(x) = 10n+5     (similar to your example of 10n)
let's imagine that f(x) = 4n^2+n+1  (similar to your example of 4n^2)

big_o(g(x)) = O(n)    *not O(10n)*
big_o(f(x)) = O(n^2)  *not O(4n^2)*
```

For the quadratics mentioned O(n) and O(n^2) are the time complexity limits

If you multiply them, for example you are performing g(x) an f(x) amount of times you can do one of the following and get the same result:

```
a)  just multiply the big O terms

   **O(n) * O(n^2) = O(n^3)**

b)  you can multiply the original quadratics, apply big O and get O(n^3) 

 let h(x) = g(x) * f(x) 
     h(x) = g(x) done f(x) times, and can be thought of as: 
 h(x) = g(x) * f(x) = (10n + 5)*(4n^2 + n +1)
               = 40n^3 + 10n^2 +10n + 20n^2 +5n + 5
          h(x) = 40n^3 + 30n^2 + 15n +5

 if you take the big O of h(x), look at the bounding polynomial 
 (n^3 and remove any mupltiplier), you get: 
         big_O( h(x) ) = O(n^3)
```

What you'll find is, the bounding time complexity polynomial is O(n^3) is going to be the answer as it is bounded by the cubic function.